# Can explain what is Client-Server model in the easiest way to explain?

Tags: client, client-server, software-design

Please, explain like a child. I'm trying to explain this concept to a junnior programmer, but I haven't accomplished that he understood the topic.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you serious? How could you teach someone something you don't understand.

Comment: @snøreven i don't think he is asking "explain me" but more "i tried explaining but he didn't understand what i told him". Now he wants another approach. At least, thats what i guessed from the question :)

Comment: @dowhilefor yes, that's what I was trying to say..

Answer (score 2):

Client-Server:

You and your friends (clients) go to the icecream man (server) and order an ice.

Peer-to-peer:

You and all your friends come together and make ice for each other.

No network:

You have no ice (or make it yourself).